# How to use the method formValueSelector of redux-form with a custom component to display an another component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I try to create a form with redux-form that display an another input when I click on custom button.

I have found sample with simple component (input, checkbox) that works but when I want use the same logic with a custom component my selector is undefined.

```
   <Field
       name="addNumberPhone"
       id="addNumberPhone"
       component={ renderButtonAddNumberPhone }
       label='Add new label'
       type="checkbox"
   />
   { addNumberPhoneValue &&
       <div>
          display something
       </div>
   }
```

My render for my custom component:

```
const renderButtonAddNumberPhone = ({ input , label , name , meta: { touched , error } }) => (
   <button id='button-add-number-phone' className='button-add-number-phone' onClick={ (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
   } }>
      <p><Icon name="plus" size={ 10 } fill="blue"/> { label }
      </p>
   </button>
)
```

and my configuration of the method *formValueSelector*:

```
const selector = formValueSelector('initializeFromState');
SampleForm = connect(state => {
    const addNumberPhoneValue = selector(state , 'addNumberPhone');    
    return {
        addNumberPhoneValue ,
    }
})(SampleForm);
```

Comment: What value do you expect to have in `addNumberPhone`? `renderButtonAddNumberPhone ` component is just a button, it doesn't have `onChange` event and any value..

Comment: in the onClick function inside `renderButtonAddNumberPhone`
what does it suppose to do? 
if you take the input value and you want to update the value in redux form, you need to use the `input.onChange(newValue)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finaly, after read with more atention the documentation of redux-form I have solved my problem using [FieldArrays](https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/fieldarrays/) tag and [formValueSelector()](https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/)

Comment: because by reading more carefully redux-form documentation I found on the fields array that respond to my need. I added the links so that people in the same problematic as me. No need for code because the explanations of the documentation are rather clear.